# mongodb java expiration

Tags: java, mongodb, document, ttl

I have a Java function which is supposed to expire documents which reach a specific date (after seven days).

```
public static void createIndex() {
    collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("expiryTime", 1), new BasicDBObject("expireAfterSeconds", 0));
}
```

This does not work.

The expiryTime in our mongo is in format:   "expiryTime" : "Mon 13 Mar 12AM".

Answer (score 0):

you havo to set expireTime as date type,just like that:

> Code Snippet

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(JSONObject.toJSONString(json, 
  SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue));
  dbObject.put("_id", id64);
  dbObject.put("expireTime",new Date(unixTime));
  mongoDBColl.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("expireTime", 1), new 
  BasicDBObject("expireAfterSeconds", 0));
  mongoDBColl.save(dbObject);
```

you can try it for test.